# Extract keywords with unique bigrams

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    key keyword score
0   0   ipsum dolor sit 50
1   0   consectetur adipiscing elit 60
2   0   ipsum dolor consectetur 80
3   0   tellus id interdum  30
4   0   ipsum interdum dolor    40
```

I want to perform a row-wise calculation to extract keywords with distinct bigrams and with highest score.

In this case **ipsum dolor sit**,**ipsum dolor consectetur**,**ipsum interdum dolor** I want to extract **ipsum dolor consectetur** as it has highest score.

So the final dataframe will look like this :

```
    key keyword score
1   0   consectetur adipiscing elit 60
2   0   ipsum dolor consectetur 80
3   0   tellus id interdum  30
```

How can I do this?

Comment: how do you define the score?

Comment: I am calculating the score using KeyBert.

Comment: how are you selecting. Why not the ipsum dolar sit 50 in the resultset?

Comment: how many rows do you have in the real dataset?

Comment: over thousands of rows and at least hundreds of keys. So basically I have one id and one desc column. Desc column is a large text. I am extracting trigrams from the text using keybert. But what is happening the bigrams are getting repeated. So I want to extract the trigrams with unique bigrams for each id and the trigram with highest score will be selected.

Comment: It would be quite easy if you had not so many rows, here you have to consider combinations of bigrams per row and the combinations of rows. Assuming 1000 rows and 100 keys, that's almost 2.5 billion total combinations to test, quite a lot… Is there any way to form groups?

Comment: nope , only thing we have is id